# XPath Selecting Node with specific parent

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<item cid="0x1310">
    <item cid="0x15ad">
    </item>

    <item cid="someOtherCode">
        <item cid="0x15ad">
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I want to select the `nodes` with `cid="0x15ad"` that are specifically under `cid="0x1310"`

So far, I have:

```
//item[not(@name='Version') and(@cid='0x1310')]//item[@cid='0x15ad']
```

The problem is that is bringing me everything plus results that are under other `cid` values.

How can I specifically retrieve the ones that are under its `parent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`//` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) selects all descendants of the current node (or the document), not just the direct children. Try this:

```
//item[not(@name='Version') and(@cid='0x1310')]/item[@cid='0x15ad']
```

But if you just want the nodes with `cid="0x15ad"` under `cid="0x1310"`, use this:

```
//item[@cid='0x1310']/item[@cid='0x15ad']
```

[**Demonstration**](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0e1ea15474d3df46a0d9eef66867ea62) (click 'Test' to see results)

Comment: Using a single `/` is what I thought, but now is not bringing anything. :/ I think I have other problems. Thanks though. My xml is more complicated and I oversimplified it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is:

```
//item[@cid="0x15ad" and ../@cid="0x1310"]
```

C# code

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<item cid=""0x1310"">
    <item cid=""0x15ad"">
    </item>

    <item cid=""someOtherCode"">
        <item cid=""0x15ad"">
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
");
var items = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(@"//item[@cid=""0x15ad"" and ../@cid=""0x1310""]").ToList();
```

Returns a list with one item.